# Render a form with initial values in WagTail

Tags: wagtail

I need to render a form, with pre-filled data but it seems to not be possible in WagTail. I'm trying to do it the "Django way" using `MyForm(initial={"field_name": value})` (`MyForm` inherits `WagtailAdminModelForm` if this is necessary), but this is not possible since `MyForm` doesn't have a `Meta.model` field and, as I understand, it cannot be specified due to how WagTail is designed.

Are there any work-arounds or alternative ways to render a pre-filled form?

Comment: You can write a regular Django Form and add the form into your template context with your Wagtail Pages Page.get_context() method.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm


class BlogForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        my_field = self.fields["my_field"]
        my_field.widget.attrs["value"] = "My new initial data"


class Blog(Page):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("my_field"),
    ] 

    base_form_class = BlogForm
```